# display only selected columns in kendo grid while edit

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hi is there any way to display only few columns while edit in Kendo Grid?

I'm trying to update grid values in popup mode. When I click on edit button it is displaying all column in popup. But I wanted to display only selected columns like name and dept in the popup.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to define your custom template for editing.Make changes like this:

In kendo grid:

```
editable: {
                    mode: "popup",
                    template: kendo.template($("#editTemplate").html())
          }
```

Define your editTemplate here like:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="editTemplate">

    <div class="k-edit-form-container">
    <table style="margin:0 auto;">
      <tr>
              <td>
                  <input type="text"  class="k-input k-textbox" **data-bind="value:your_column_to_bind"**/>
              </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
 </script>
```